# Referencing child data in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

[firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEONP.png)

I need to fetch data from firebase database(Check the link for data structure snap) I am able to get data of "dueDate" through {{currentBill?.dueDate}} but don't know how to get data of other items above it. Following is the code used to fetch data:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.firebaseData.getBillDetail(this.navParams.get('billId'))
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    this.currentBill = snapshot.val();
    this.currentBill.id = snapshot.key;
  });

}
```

Also I do not want to restructure the data structure... I am unable to find reference to the key. I am working with Angular in Ionic

Comment: Is there any way to get snap of child data from the above function of the currentBill?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more thoroughly, you could add the output of `console.log(snapshot)` to your question for better debugging.

I'm curious if the data is present in the snapshot, you can verify that by using `console.log(snapshot)`. If it is available you could do something like the following to fetch the other items:

```js
snapshot.forEach((billSnapshot) => {
  console.log(billSnapshot.val());
});
```

This would maybe point you more in the right direction, you could use something like this:

```js
snapshot.forEach((billSnapshot) => {
  console.log(billSnapshot.val());
  switch(billSnapshot.key) {
  case 'dueDate': 
    this.bill.dueDate = billSnapshot.val(); 
    break;
   // Add here other variables you know the name of
  default:
    //Push all the unknown keys to an array you can use later 
    //on your bill object
    this.bill.keys.push(billSnapshot.val())
  }
});
```

Hope this helps and points you in the right direction,